# How to pass id from blog articel to readmore child component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, components

I am trying to build a blog with api and i can render all blog posts  as list but i have a read more button for each blog post and i want to build a child component which show the more about blog post. I know i have to build in router a new url and pass with id and push the id as props in new child component but somehow i cant render details about blog post.my blog list in blogarticel.js and i want to render details in Blogpost.js Thats way i need your help.

```js
import './App.css';
import Work from './components/Work'
import About from './components/About'

import Blog from './components/Blog'
import BlogPost from './components/BlogPost'
import Contact from './components/Contact'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer'


import Fashion from './components/works/Fashion'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'


function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="App">

        <Header/>
        <Routes>
  
          <Route path="/" element={<Work />}/>
          <Route path="/About" element={<About />}/>
          <Route path="/Blog" element={<Blog />}/>
          <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact />}/>
          <Route path="/Blog/:id" element={<BlogPost />}/>
         
          <Route path="/Fashion" element={<Fashion />}/>

        
        </Routes>   
      
        <Footer/>
      
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import '../styles/Container.css';
import {Link, NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

const BlogArticel = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(props.posts)) {
      
      setData(props.posts)
    }
  },[props.posts])

  const renderItems = () => {
    let apiResults = [...data]
    let bioData = []

    if (apiResults) {
      
      apiResults.forEach(ele => {
     
        if (ele && ele.caption.includes('#loeilblog')) {
          bioData.push(
            <div className="container_place">
                    <div className="text_containers">
                    <img className="container_img" key={ele.id} src={ele.media_url} alt="image"/>

                        <div className="container_text">

                        <p className="blog_username" key={ele.id}>{ele.username}    <span className="blog_date" key={ele.id}>{ele.timestamp.slice(0, 10)} </span> </p>
                 
                     

                           <p className="bio_caption" key={ele.id}>{(ele.caption.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')).split(/\s+/).slice(0,30).join(" ").concat('...')}</p>
                           <NavLink  to="/Blog/:id" key={this.ele.id}>
                           <button className="site_button" >Read more</button>
                          </NavLink>

                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
          )
        }
      });
    }

    return bioData;

  }
        return (
          <div>
            
            {renderItems()} 
          </div>
        )
    }

    export default BlogArticel;
```

```js
import React from 'react'

function BlogPost(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      ?????
    </div>
  )
}

export default BlogPost
```

lot.

Comment: You should redirect the user to the blog post page. Once here you can get the id of the blog post from the router.